# Order of variables in specific sections when enabling optimization in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

Here is an extremely simple test case:

```
int a __attribute__ ((section("section")));
int b __attribute__ ((section("section")));
int c __attribute__ ((section("section")));
```

If I compile this file with GCC 8, with no optimizations and dump the object file I get the variables in the exact order as in the source file:

```
$ gcc -c order.c
$ nm -n order.o
0000000000000000 D a
0000000000000004 D b
0000000000000008 D c
```

However if I enable the optimization (any level), the variables are reversed in memory:

```
$ gcc -O -c order.c
$ nm -n order.o
0000000000000000 D c
0000000000000004 D b
0000000000000008 D a
```

As I need to keep consistent addresses of various variables in specific memory section for different versions of the program, I decided to put all of these variables in the same source file. This is for an embedded project and the section of memory I'm using has backup battery power, so its contents are not lost when the device is powered down. However I also need the addresses of "old" objects to remain constant and I don't want them to change when I add some "new" objects.

So I'm wondering whether this particular behavior of GCC is something which I could control with any compiler flag (other than disabling optimizations [; ) and whether this is something consistent across different versions of GCC? For example can I assume that in GCC 11, in year 2022, the order of the variables in the memory will still be reverse of the order in source file, or maybe someday the order will be different than today with GCC 8?

Comment: As far as I know, this is because of the way the memory is managed.
The variables are put in the stack part of the memory. This part grows as the memory needs grow. As it grows from right to left, the latest variable defined is the left-most in the memory.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer - these are not stack variables and not all architectures have "descending" stack.

Comment: 1. You can't rely on how given compiler in given version with specified optimization level lays out variables in memory. 2. If this is not to much trouble you may consider putting those variables inside struct and apply section attribute to it. It will preserve order of variables and is portable (whereas 1) is not.

Comment: Since you put all the declarations in one file.  Can  you can disable optimization for the particular file and only enable optimization for other files?